# How to scale a pixelimage using only SVG on Safari

Tags: css, svg, safari

This Question is an extension to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71285824/scaled-up-low-resolution-pixel-image-element-in-svg-blurry-on-safari-but-not-in) one. I'm having troubles scaling an Pixelimage to look not blurry in Safari. From what i understood safari can't use `image-rendering`. The workaround proposed in the linked thread seems to require an external style sheet (?). Is it possible to scale the image (not blurry) in one svg / without external stylesheet?

Some Things i tried (and failed):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- the embedded css seem to work here ? -->
    <svg
      class="svgBG"
      viewBox="0 0 50 50"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    ></svg>
    

    <svg viewBox="0 0 50 50"
  <defs id="someDefs">
    <style id="style2">
      .svgBG {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: #15ff00;
        background-image: url(data:image/png;charset:utf-8;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyCAYAAAAeP4ixAAAAZklEQVR4nO3XQQ6AIAwEQPD/f64nE/WoLFEy84CWppSG1gAASOnJ4FVVl2S9x/JtqcBLOTpy70xCvCMzi4mZefhlhh1CXt/Zp3PwufkZ8TKNiGGzA0DaeWOn/ybLbPZlCgEAAH5nBzIvM+pVaumQAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%;
        image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
        -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;
        image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
        image-rendering: pixelated;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  
   <!-- dosent render-->
 <!-- <rect x="0" y="0" height="1" width="1" class="svgBG" />   -->
 
<!-- dosen't work-->
 <svg
 class="svgBG"
 viewBox="0 0 5 5"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 ></svg>
 
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can't apply a css background-image to svg elements like `<rect>` but you can apply them to the parent svg itself or use a `<foreignObject>` as described in the aforementioned answer. Currently, you're code doesn't render anything. Could you provide a mockup/screenshot what you#re trying to achieve?

Comment: yes - <foreignObject> solves this - thx

Answer (score 0):

It works indeed with `<foreignObject>` as the aforementioned answer described.
Code than looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> </head>
  <body style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0)">
    <svg width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <style>
        img {
          height: 500px;
          width: 500px;
          image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
          -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;
          image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
          image-rendering: pixelated;
        }
      </style>

      <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500">
        <img
          src="data:image/png;charset:utf-8;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyCAYAAAAeP4ixAAAAZklEQVR4nO3XQQ6AIAwEQPD/f64nE/WoLFEy84CWppSG1gAASOnJ4FVVl2S9x/JtqcBLOTpy70xCvCMzi4mZefhlhh1CXt/Zp3PwufkZ8TKNiGGzA0DaeWOn/ybLbPZlCgEAAH5nBzIvM+pVaumQAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"
      /></foreignObject>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```